# Group Criteria API query's results by the day part of a date

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

In Criteria API i have to group the results of a query based on the day part of a date column returned in the query. Can you please suggest how to do this?

The following is the multiselect query

**cq.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("recievedOn")) ;**

where recievedOn is the date column. I want to groupBy the query based on the day, week, month and year. Can you please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a GROUP BY, then you can only select by fields that you grouped by, or apply an aggregate function (count/min/max/etc), so I'm not sure what you are trying to do?

It is easy enough to group by the date, but if you only want to group by a specific part of the date then you need to use a function.  The Criteria API does not define any date functions, but you can use the function() API to call a specific database function.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Group_By

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Criteria_API_special_functions

If you are using EclipseLink you can also combine Expression objects with Criteria for additional function support,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#JpaCriteriaBuilder_and_EclipseLink_Extensions

Or you could use JPQL, which has more extensions,

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_extract.htm#extract